# i want to save data in nativescript using API, but error JS: [Error: Network error: Converting circular structure to JSON]

Tags: api, button, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i want to save result in nativescript, but show error JS: [Error: Network error: Converting circular structure to JSON]

in list.vue i push the id from each button +/-. here is the code

```
confirm() {
          // The result property is true if the dialog is closed with the OK button, false if closed with the Cancel button or undefined if closed with a neutral button.
          this.duhmboh=[]
          this.pageData.forEach((element,index) => {
            if(element.qty>0){
              this.duhmboh.push({
                id:element.id,
                guest: this.guests[index],
                qty: element
              })
            }
          });
          this.duhmboh.forEach(element => {
            console.log("DUMBOH",element)
          });
          this.$showModal(modal, {
            props: {
              tempData: this.duhmboh
            },
            fullscreen: false,
            animated: false,
            stretched: false,
            dimAmount: 0.2, 
            dismissEnabled: false
          })
      },
```

and the modal.vue is like this

```
save(qty) {
            if (this.is_saving) return
            this.is_saving = true
            var vm = this

            this.$apollo.query({
                query: gqlUseVoucher,
                variables: {
                    id: this.pageData.id,
                    qty_used: qty
                },
                fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
            }).then((resp) => {
                if (resp.room.AuthorizeVoucherUsingID) {
                    vm.is_saving = false
                    vm.$modal.close()
                    vm.$store.commit('setSuccess', 'Voucher breakfast berhasil divalidasi')
                } else {
                    vm.is_saving = false
                    errorHandler(vm, null, 'Voucher breakfast tidak dapat digunakan')
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                vm.is_saving = false
                console.log(error)
                errorHandler(vm, error)
            })
        },
```

and i still cant click the button ssave. what should i do?

Comment: Your data seem to include circular references can't be serialized. I see that you are using GraphQL. Whats the value of gqlUseVoucher? did you try logging it?

Comment: yes i using graphql. the value of gplUseVoucher is just id and qty_used. helpmeee

Comment: Did you track it further, able to find which line is exactly throwing the error. May be a complete error log might help.

Comment: yes, the qty is undefined, and when i debug android theres no variable

Comment: undefined should not throw this issue. It must be some non-serializable object in your request. Did you notice whether the error is thrown after API call or before?

Comment: I would suggest you to add a complete error to get more info about the exception, otherwise a Playground sample will help to track the issue.

Comment: i guest after API call._., and the error showing when i click the oke button. Btw am new in nativescript. So sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209748/discussion-between-trya-sovi-kartikasari-and-manoj).